# emacs elisp send line if no region active python-mode

Tags: python, emacs, elisp

I want to create a command where the region is sent if active, and if not, the current line/statement is evaluated and point is taken further to the next statement.

I started with [This solution.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2010-08/msg00429.html)
Now I can't get the (python-shell-send-region) to work though as I don't know how to pass the beginning and end of the region to it.

So far I have this:

```
 (defun my-python-send-region (&optional beg end)   
   (interactive)   
    (if (use-region-p)
      (python-shell-send-region)    (let ((beg (cond (beg beg)
                    ((region-active-p)
                     (region-beginning))
                    (t (line-beginning-position))))
         (end (cond (end end)
                    ((region-active-p)
                     (copy-marker (region-end)))
                    (t (line-end-position)))))
     (python-shell-send-region beg end)
     (python-nav-forward-statement))))

 (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
       (lambda ()
     (define-key python-mode-map "\C-cn" 'my-python-send-region)))
```

UPDATE: 
With Andreas' and Legoscia's suggestions I changed the structure a bit.

Now I get an error *(Invalid function: (setq beg (point))* for:

```
 (defun my-python-send-region (&optional beg end)
  (interactive)
  (if (use-region-p)
    (python-shell-send-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
   ((setq beg (point))
    (python-nav-end-of-statement)
    (setq end (point))
    (python-shell-send-region (beg) (end)))
    (python-nav-forward-statement))))
```

However, this works:

```
 (defun my-python-send-region (&optional beg end)
 (interactive)
 (setq beg (point))
 (python-nav-end-of-statement)
 (setq end (point))
 (python-shell-send-region beg end))
```

Comment: Sending a region or line is error-prone due to Pythons sensitiveness WRT whitespaces. Rather use commands adressing Python forms at point - sending block, statement, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach which might work is to try the whole-line-or-region package from melpa. This package sets up things so that if you call a command which expects a region, but no region is defined, it will basically set a region which is equal to the current line. Essentially, this causes commands which expect a region to work when no region is defined on the current line. I have this in my init.org file

> Allow region oriented commands to work on the current line if no
>   region is    defined.

```
   #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
     (use-package whole-line-or-region
       :ensure t
       :diminish whole-line-or-region-mode
       :config
       (whole-line-or-region-mode t)
       (make-variable-buffer-local 'whole-line-or-region-mode))
```

Comment: it doesn't move one line ahead, but I can fix it by recording a quick macro when I use it a lot

Answer (score 1):

In this part:

```lisp
(if (use-region-p)
  (python-shell-send-region)
```

you need to pass the beginning and end of the region to `python-shell-send-region`.  It only gets those values automatically when called interactively.  When you call it from Lisp code, you need to pass the values explicitly:

```lisp
(python-shell-send-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: the python-shell-send-defun does not always send the current statement/line ([it is not meant to do that](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/793)), so I replaced it with a function from elpy

```
(defun python-shell-send-region-or-line nil
  "Sends from python-mode buffer to a python shell, intelligently."
  (interactive)
  (cond ((region-active-p)
     (setq deactivate-mark t)
     (python-shell-send-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
 ) (t (python-shell-send-current-statement))))

(defun python-shell-send-current-statement ()
"Send current statement to Python shell.
Taken from elpy-shell-send-current-statement"
(interactive)
(let ((beg (python-nav-beginning-of-statement))
    (end (python-nav-end-of-statement)))
(python-shell-send-string (buffer-substring beg end)))
(python-nav-forward-statement))
```

I use cond for if in case I want to add cases. Setting deactivate-mark is to deselect the region if selected. If no region is selected, I also navigate forward a python statement.

Comment: When I use this without an active region, I get error: 'Wrong number of Arguments: (1 . 1), 0

Comment: the "wrong number of arg..." was from a move-end-of-line in the previous answer, which needed an argument nil. The updated answer has that functioned removed anyway.

Comment: This is very nice - the only glitch now is that it jumps ahead one statement even if a region is selected, which might make you miss part of your code if you keep going continuously.

Comment: On my emacs, when a region is selected, it will send the region to the interpreter and unselect the region without moving forward one statement. If a region is not selected, then it will send the current statement AND move one statement forward. If you want to not move a statement forward, then remove (python-nav-forward-statement) from python-shell-send-current-statement. Or you might want to replace (python-nav-forward-statement) with (next-line) (move-end-of-line nil)